# adding some pods cause FirebaseApp.configure() to have identifier issue

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

when i add pod 'Firebase/Auth' pod 'Firebase/Database' and pod 'Firebase/Storage' FirebaseApp.configure() has the error use of unresolved identifier FirebaseApp.configure() (I've tried FIRApp it doesn't work what so ever) my pod file look like this https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SEFHtnIChdkCfgHl3v2CMbh3zlbfYp1_v44YFgrDCeY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you put `import Firebase` in your swift file?

Comment: Please include the content of pod file in the question itself rather than a link to Google Docs. This is so that if the google doc file was deleted/changed in the future, the question is still valid.

Comment: Which Xcode are you using and Firebase Version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I fixed the problem for anyone who's having these kinda problem just download a different version of Xcode I had 7.3.1 when having this problem and downgraded to 7.0.0